# VSCode httpClient plugin showing Header name must be a valid HTTP token

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this API call in the VSCode RESTAPI caller plugin:

```
###
POST {{endpoint}}/snapcenter/SnapCenterInventory/account/{{accountId}}  {{@protocol}}
content-type: application/json
Authorization: {{token}}
        {
            "Server": "10.10.10.10",
            "ApplicationCount": 10,
            "User": "admin",
            "Password": "foo",
            "Port": 3000,
            "RoleName": "bar"
        }

###
```

I have all the variables defined, working fine in GET cases.

However for POST/PATCH/PUT, it's giving this error:

```
Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["{"]
```

Not able to figure out what I am missing here.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 0):

I think I can able to find it out. I need to keep a newline b/w the header and the content.

This works:

```
POST {{endpoint}}/servers/account/{{accountId}}  {{@protocol}}
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: {{token}}

{
    "k1": "v5",
    "k2": 110,
    "k3": true,
    "k4": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    "k5": {
        "k51": "v5",
        "k52": 2
    },
    "k6": {
        "k61": true
    }
}
```

Mind the gap b/w the content and the header.